# Neural Network for MNIST digits is not learning at all - problem with backpropagation

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation

after a long time, I am still not able to run my nn without any bugs. Accuracy of this toy nn is an astonishing 1-2% (60 neurons in hidden layer, 100 epochs, 0.3 learning rate, tanh activation, MNIST dataset downloaded via TF) - so basically it is not learning at all. After all this time looking at videos / post about backpropagation, I am still not able to fix it. 
So my bug must be in between the part marked with two ##### lines. I think that my understanding of derivatives in general is good, but I just cannot connect this knowlege with backpropagation.
If the backpropagation base is correct, then the mistake must at `axis = 0/1`, because I also cannot understand, how to determine on which axis I will be working on.

Also, I have a strong feeling, that `dZ2 = A2 - Y` might be wrong, it should be `dZ2 = Y - A2`, but after that correction, nn starts to guess only one number.

(and yes, backpropagation itself I haven't written, I have found it on the internet)

```py
#importing data and normalizing it
#"x_test" will be my X
#"y_test" will be my Y

import tensorflow as tf
(traindataX, traindataY), (testdataX, testdataY) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_test = testdataX.reshape(testdataX.shape[0], testdataX.shape[1]**2).astype('float32')
x_test = x_test / 255

y_test = testdataY
y_test = np.eye(10)[y_test]
```

```py
#Activation functions:
def tanh(z):
    a = (np.exp(z)-np.exp(-z))/(np.exp(z)+np.exp(-z))
    return a
###############################################################################START
def softmax(z):
    smExp = np.exp(z - np.max(z, axis=0))
    out = smExp / np.sum(smExp, axis=0)
    return out
###############################################################################STOP
```

```py
def neural_network(num_hid, epochs, 
                  learning_rate, X, Y):
    #num_hid - number of neurons in the hidden layer
    #X - dataX - shape (10000, 784)
    #Y - labels - shape (10000, 10)

    #inicialization
    W1 = np.random.randn(784, num_hid) * 0.01
    W2 = np.random.randn(num_hid, 10) * 0.01
    b1 = np.zeros((1, num_hid))
    b2 = np.zeros((1, 10))
    correct = 0

    for x in range(1, epochs+1):
        #feedforward
        Z1 = np.dot(X, W1) + b1
        A1 = tanh(Z1)
        Z2 = np.dot(A1, W2) + b2
        A2 = softmax(Z2)


        ###############################################################################START
        m = X.shape[1] #-> 784
        loss = - np.sum((Y * np.log(A2)), axis=0, keepdims=True)
        cost = np.sum(loss, axis=1) / m

        #backpropagation
        dZ2 = A2 - Y
        dW2 = (1/m)*np.dot(A1.T, dZ2)
        db2 = (1/m)*np.sum(dZ2, axis = 1, keepdims = True)
        dZ1 = np.multiply(np.dot(dZ2, W2.T), 1 - np.power(A1, 2))
        dW1 = (1/m)*np.dot(X.T, dZ1)
        db1 = (1/m)*np.sum(dZ1, axis = 1, keepdims = True)
        ###############################################################################STOP


        #parameters update - gradient descent
        W1 = W1 - dW1*learning_rate
        b1 = b1 - db1*learning_rate
        W2 = W2 - dW2*learning_rate
        b2 = b2 - db2*learning_rate


        for i in range(np.shape(Y)[1]):
            guess = np.argmax(A2[i, :])
            ans = np.argmax(Y[i, :])
            print(str(x) + " " + str(i) + ". " +"guess: ", guess, "| ans: ", ans)
            if guess == ans:
                correct = correct + 1;

    accuracy = (correct/np.shape(Y)[0]) * 100
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip, but could you help me with backpropagation?

Comment: Backpropagation is *extremely* hard to get right. Unless you really need to do it, I strongly recommend using packages made by people who have already spend countless hours tweaking it to make it correct in every aspect (without any guarantees that it's actually right in every aspect, but at least it will work, most of the time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lucas,
Good problem to refresh the fundamentals. I made a few fixes to your code:

- calculation of m
- Transposed all weights and biases (can't explain properly, but it was not working otherwise).
- changed calculation of accuracy (and loss, which is not used).

See the corrected code below. It gets to 90% accuracy with your original parameters:

```
def neural_network(num_hid, epochs, learning_rate, X, Y):
#num_hid - number of neurons in the hidden layer
#X - dataX - shape (10000, 784)
#Y - labels - shape (10000, 10)

#inicialization
# W1 = np.random.randn(784, num_hid) * 0.01
# W2 = np.random.randn(num_hid, 10) * 0.01
# b1 = np.zeros((1, num_hid))
# b2 = np.zeros((1, 10))
W1 = np.random.randn(num_hid, 784) * 0.01
W2 = np.random.randn(10, num_hid) * 0.01
b1 = np.zeros((num_hid, 1))
b2 = np.zeros((10, 1))

for x in range(1, epochs+1):
    correct = 0  # moved inside cycle
    #feedforward
    # Z1 = np.dot(X, W1) + b1
    Z1 = np.dot(W1, X.T) + b1
    A1 = tanh(Z1)
    # Z2 = np.dot(A1, W2) + b2
    Z2 = np.dot(W2, A1) + b2
    A2 = softmax(Z2)

    ###############################################################################START
    m = X.shape[0] #-> 784  # SHOULD BE NUMBER OF SAMPLES IN THE BATCH
    # loss = - np.sum((Y * np.log(A2)), axis=0, keepdims=True)
    loss = - np.sum((Y.T * np.log(A2)), axis=0, keepdims=True)
    cost = np.sum(loss, axis=1) / m

    #backpropagation
    # dZ2 = A2 - Y
    # dW2 = (1/m)*np.dot(A1.T, dZ2)
    # db2 = (1/m)*np.sum(dZ2, axis = 1, keepdims = True)
    # dZ1 = np.multiply(np.dot(dZ2, W2.T), 1 - np.power(A1, 2))
    # dW1 = (1/m)*np.dot(X.T, dZ1)
    dZ2 = A2 - Y.T
    dW2 = (1/m)*np.dot(dZ2, A1.T)
    db2 = (1/m)*np.sum(dZ2, axis = 1, keepdims = True)
    dZ1 = np.multiply(np.dot(W2.T, dZ2), 1 - np.power(A1, 2))
    dW1 = (1/m)*np.dot(dZ1, X)

    db1 = (1/m)*np.sum(dZ1, axis = 1, keepdims = True)
    ###############################################################################STOP

    #parameters update - gradient descent
    W1 = W1 - dW1*learning_rate
    b1 = b1 - db1*learning_rate
    W2 = W2 - dW2*learning_rate
    b2 = b2 - db2*learning_rate

    guess = np.argmax(A2, axis=0)  # axis fixed
    ans = np.argmax(Y, axis=1)  # axis fixed
    # print (guess.shape, ans.shape)
    correct += sum (guess==ans)

    #     #print(str(x) + " " + str(i) + ". " +"guess: ", guess, "| ans: ", ans)
    #     if guess == ans:
    #         correct = correct + 1;
    accuracy = correct / x_test.shape[0]
    print (f"Epoch {x}. accuracy = {accuracy*100:.2f}%")


neural_network (64, 100, 0.3, x_test, y_test)

Epoch 1. accuracy = 14.93%
Epoch 2. accuracy = 34.70%
Epoch 3. accuracy = 47.41%
(...)
Epoch 98. accuracy = 89.29%
Epoch 99. accuracy = 89.33%
Epoch 100. accuracy = 89.37%
```

Comment: Why do you do {1 - np.power(A1)}? Shouldn't it be (1-A1) * A1?

Comment: to @Andyyy1012:  you refer here to inverse tanh() function. I took mine from this example: https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-build-2-layer-neural-network-from-scratch-in-python-4dd44a13ebba. Surprisingly, yours works too, just learns slower.

Comment: Yes my bad, that is the derivative of the tanh(), don't use the one I posted, its the derivative of sigmoid

Comment: Also shouldn't you divide the correct by test examples not the features?

Comment: Andy, `x_test.shape[0]` is the number of examples.

Answer (score 2):

It might be because you should normalize your inputs between the values of 0 and 1 by dividing X by 255 (255 is max pixel value). You should also have Y one hot encoded as series of size 10 vectors. I think your backprop is right, but you should implement gradient checking to double check.

Comment: I am sorry, this was my fault. I completely forgot to add these important things to my question, but I already had them in my code.
I tried once Gradient Checking and I found nothing, but now thanks to you, I will try again and will see, if this time, I will find anything. 
Thanks for the tip btw :D

Comment: The underlying problem might be something else tho, i'm also having trouble with something but idk what in my case

Comment: Also m should not be 784, it should be the amount of training examples in which your case is 10000. And a2 - Y is correct

Answer (score 2):

You are calculating accuracy in the wrong way.
First correct variable should be initialized to 0 for each iteration of an epoch, second 
if y.shape is (10000, 10), then for calculating  accuracy, loop should be `for i in range(np.shape(Y)[0])` not `for i in range(np.shape(Y)[1])` , the first one will iterate for 10,000 times the second one will iterate for 10 times.

A better approach will be to use NumPy to calculate the number of correct guesses `correct = np.sum(np.argmax(A2,axis=1) == np.argmax(Y,axis=1))`

Your learning rate is too high, I was able to achieve 50% accuracy by setting learning rate to 0.003 for 50 epoch and 60 hidden neuron

```
def neural_network(num_hid, epochs, 
                  learning_rate, X, Y):
    #num_hid - number of neurons in the hidden layer
    #X - dataX - shape (10000, 784)
    #Y - labels - shape (10000, 10)

    #inicialization
    W1 = np.random.randn(784, num_hid) * 0.01
    W2 = np.random.randn(num_hid, 10) * 0.01
    b1 = np.zeros((1, num_hid))
    b2 = np.zeros((1, 10))
    correct = 0

    for x in range(1, epochs+1):
        #feedforward
        Z1 = np.dot(X, W1) + b1
        A1 = tanh(Z1)
        Z2 = np.dot(A1, W2) + b2
        A2 = softmax(Z2)


        ###############################################################################START
        m = X.shape[1] #-> 784
        loss = - np.sum((Y * np.log(A2)), axis=0, keepdims=True)
        cost = np.sum(loss, axis=1) / m

        #backpropagation
        dZ2 = A2 - Y
        dW2 = (1/m)*np.dot(A1.T, dZ2)
        db2 = (1/m)*np.sum(dZ2, axis = 1, keepdims = True)
        dZ1 = np.multiply(np.dot(dZ2, W2.T), 1 - np.power(A1, 2))
        dW1 = (1/m)*np.dot(X.T, dZ1)
        db1 = (1/m)*np.sum(dZ1, axis = 1, keepdims = True)
        ###############################################################################STOP


        #parameters update - gradient descent
        W1 = W1 - dW1*learning_rate
        b1 = b1 - db1*learning_rate
        W2 = W2 - dW2*learning_rate
        b2 = b2 - db2*learning_rate

        correct = 0
        for i in range(np.shape(Y)[0]):
            guess = np.argmax(A2[i, :])
            ans = np.argmax(Y[i, :])
#             print(str(x) + " " + str(i) + ". " +"guess: ", guess, "| ans: ", ans)
            if guess == ans:
                correct = correct + 1

#         correct = np.sum(np.argmax(A2,axis=1) == np.argmax(Y,axis=1))
#         print(correct)
        accuracy = (correct/np.shape(Y)[0]) * 100
        print(accuracy)
```

You need to be experimental, for good accuracy, try tuning number of hidden layer , epoch and learning rate.